# Laravel Eloquent "Many-to-Many-to-One ?"

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

My database schema:

```
user:
    - id
    - email
    ...

notification_user:
    - user_id
    - notification_id

notifications:
    - id
    - channel_id
    - message
    ...

channels:
    - id
    - name
    ...
```

User Model:

```
public function notifications()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Notification');
}
```

Notification Model:

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
}
```

**What is the problem:**
`App\User::find(1)->notifications` shows all notifications which belongs to this user and it works fine, but I also need to include data from `channels` table.

```
<App\Notification #000000004e6906c1000000014ed0d97c> {
   id: 20,
   channel_id: 3,
   message: "...",
   created_at: "2015-05-31 17:37:12",
   updated_at: "2015-06-07 10:37:12",
   pivot: <Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot #000000004e690718000000014ed0d97c> {
       user_id: 1,
       notification_id: 20
   }
},
```

The above is output from tinker. **Question is:** How to include data from `channels` table for every notification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `Channel` relationship to `Notification` model.

```
public function channel()
{
    $this->belongsTo('App\Channel');
}
```

Then you can load the notifications with channel like below.

```
App\User::with('notifications', 'notifications.channel')->find(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a one-to-many relationship between `Channel` model and `Notification` model.

Notification Model:

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
}

public function channel()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Channel');
}
```

Chanel model:

```
public function notifications()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Notification');
}
```

And then you can access the channel for each notification.

```
$channel = $notification->channel;
```

Comment: Your example looks more elegant, but if I will do it, then it will do a huge amount of queries to database.

Comment: You can use eager loading as indicated in @chanafdo's answer.